# Benelli TNT 150 has how many valves?

Tags: motorcycle, valve

I know my question is out of topic but could anyone tell me if Benelli TNT 150 has 4 valves or 2? Internet wasn't helpful. I am also confused between Benelli TNT 150 and TNT 15.

Thanks

**EDIT**

To make my mean more clear, I added [this](https://www.pakwheels.com/blog/benelli-tnt-150i-review-specs-photos/) as an opposition to the David's answer where it said it has 4-valves. In other words, I said internet wasnt helpful cause it resulted into different answers.

> The bike is equipped with 149.5cc single-cylinder **4-valve** engine that produces 14hp at 9000 rpm and 11.5nm of torque at 7000 rpm. It has two spark plugs, while the basic model has a single spark plug. The advantage of having two spark plug is that the fuel consumption of the bike will be good.

Comment: Lots of errors in that quote - is it from the original manufacturer? If not they may have posted the wrong write-up meant for a different machine...

Answer (score 1):

The internet was easily helpful to me. I searched for "Benelli 150 TNT" and quickly found [this page](https://www.motorcyclevalley.com/specs/benelli-tnt-150/), which informed me that this motorcycle has an engine with 2 valves.

[image]

Comment: @Moab Nice edit!

Comment: You are welcome David!

Comment: Not so fast Sir. You think I didnt search on the internet. When I said it wasnt helpful, I was referring to paradoxical information. Some says it has 2 valves while some other says [it has 4!](https://www.pakwheels.com/blog/benelli-tnt-150i-review-specs-photos/)

Comment: What makes it even worse is the fact that in some cases, they confused TNT 15 with 150.

Comment: @lonesome The page you cite in your comment shows a TNT 150i, a different machine than the one you asked about in your question. The TNT 150 motor is air-cooled and has 2 valves; the TNT 150i motor is oil-cooled, has 4 valves, and produces more power. They also, at least, have different bodywork and different paint schemes.